# regular expression in texstudio

Tags: texstudio, regular-expressions

My objective is to replace math delimiters path `$...$` by `\(...\)`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
    This is a sample text $ \sin\alpha $ and $ \cos\alpha. $
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} $
        \item $ \tan\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha} $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Expected output:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
    This is a sample text  \( \sin\alpha \)  and  \( \cos\alpha. \) 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item  \( \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \) 
        \item  \( \tan\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha} \) 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can we do this in ***TeXstudio*** TeX editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a macro for that to make the replacement in one click or with a press of the shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+1 in the example).

```js
%SCRIPT
regexParsed = editor.text().replace(/([^\$\\])\$([^\$]+)\$/gm, '$1\\($2\\)').replace(/\r/g, '');
editor.setText(regexParsed)
```

This approach also takes into account `$$` display math and dollar signs in a text `\$`, so that your project won't break in case there are some of them.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work if the two $'s are not on the same line (my solution too) This is a feature missing from TeXStudio regular expressions.

Comment: See  this minimal example on pastebin http://ix.io/3QZW . You can have surprising results. You should use an interactive way, as I do.

Comment: If needed, one can always test their regular expressions in https://regexr.com/. About double `$$`, if it's not desired, one can always substitute all ``$$`` in sequence for one `$` and then the order substitution. Indeed, it is as easy as writing both `editor.replace` commands in sequence. I've faced some problems which breaking it into pieces made the regular expression a lot more easier.

Comment: @gigiair thank you for the issue report. I edited the code to take into account this situation as well.

Answer (score 3):

Search and replace (Ctrl R) `(^|[^$\\])\$([^\$]+)\$` with `\1\(\2\)`

Comment: This won't work as expected if the OP has `$$` display math, so the document will be corrupted. You need to add an additional check for this situation.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case because $$ is TeX and its use is deprecated in LaTeX. It must first replace $$..$$ with \\[..\\]

Comment: Note that the main downside is that it doesn't work if the two $s aren't on the same line. It's possible with Emacs, but in TeXStudio I'm afraid it's not possible. Emacs regular expressions are much more powerful than TeXStudio regular expressions.

Comment: @gigiair I have already tested with TeXstudio 4.2.2 and as have mentioned, it doesn't works when the pair $,$ is not in the same line. Your answer is helpful to the community and I have learned something new form it.

Comment: @antshar I fixed the regex for the bug you reported. I think it's not a good idea to make a macro because you have to manually check if the pair of $ is not on the same line and TS regexps are not able to do that. Looks at my MWE upward.

Comment: @gigiair For your new update, I experience of incorrect placement of mathematical formula `math \( \)`. Anyway, it works pretty fine if I replace with `\(\2\)`.